# How to get the most feats for a spellcaster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optimization, spellcasting

I have an idea for a spellcaster character but it needs as many feats as possible.

I'm aware that things that grant bonus feats are rare or non-existant. I don't really need any feats, just spellcaster-relevant feats - you know, Spell Focus, Spell Penetration, Metamagic feats and such.

Things like Fighter bonus feats are ofc irrelevant here since it only grants combat feats and I wouldn't get spell slots.

**Is there a way to get more spellcasting feats than the obvious Human Wizard?**

---

Loremaster prestige class can grant a bonus feat at first level while progressing spellcasting which is good. The catch is that it requires a Skill Focus feat as prerequisite which makes it useless unless there is a way to get Skill Focus as a bonus feat somehow.

---

Constraints and limits:

- class is not important, but it should be one with full spellcasting progression (having lvl 9 spells in the end) - I don't consider other classes as spellcasters
- spontaneous or prepares is not important
- race is not important, human was only picked as obvious for the bonus feat
- not restricting materials on purpose, I'll check the answers for sources but wish to know what's where even if I can't use it - someone else might
- there is no target number of feats, just as many spellcasting feats as possible
- spell progression is important but losing 1-2 levels of spell progression might be acceptable depending on the tradeoff
- level was not specified on purpose, we're around lvl 15 at the moment but ofc wanna know about higher level possibilities as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Elf Exploiter wizard.

Elves gain access to the following [alternate racial traits](https://aonprd.com/RacesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Elf):*

> **Overwhelming Magic:** Some elves obsess over the fundamentals of magic, training for decades to add layers of potent spellwork before they ever begin practicing true spells.  This builds a foundation that makes their magic increasingly difficult to resist. These elves gain Spell Focus as a bonus feat.  This racial trait replaces elven magic and weapon familiarity.

> **Illustrious Urbanite:** City elves have a remarkable ability to combine magic harmoniously with their surroundings.  They gain Spell Focus with conjuration, illusion, or transmutation spells as a bonus feat.  When casting spells of this school, the elves can choose to have the spell leave undamaged any building or structure that would normally be affected.  This racial trait replaces keen senses.
>  *Note: not PFS-legal.*

Wizards with the Exploiter archetype keep their bonus feats every 5 levels, and also gain access to the following [arcanist exploits](https://aonprd.com/ArcanistExploits.aspx):

> **Item Crafting:** The arcanist can select one item creation feat as a bonus feat.  She must meet the prerequisites of this feat.
>  *Note: not PFS-legal, not sure if this one meets your criteria or not.*

> **Metamagic Knowledge:** The arcanist can select one metamagic feat as a bonus feat.  She must meet the prerequisites of this feat.

Putting it all together, by level 20 you would have two Spell Focus feats from your race, ten standard feats, four wizard feats plus Scribe Scroll (unless you can convince your GM to swap it out for Spell Focus like in PFS), and one metamagic feat from your exploit for a total of **18 spellcasting feats** (19 if you count the Item Crafting exploit).

---

<sub>* Elves also have an alternate racial trait that gives them Skill Focus as a bonus feat, which would qualify you for Loremaster and allow you to take any one feat, but it would take the place of the Overwhelming Magic trait so this option essentially trades Spell Focus at level 1 for whatever you want eventually. It's up to you whether that trade is worth it.</sub>

Comment: Re: Your note at the end - a loremaster dip also costs you the final bonus feat granted by Wizard, which puts you down a feat overall.

Comment: Trying to break it down:
10 - standard progression, 2 - race, 4 - wizard bonus feats, 1 - exploiter, 1 - Scribe Scroll - is that correct?

Comment: I don't really count Scribe Scroll so it's 17 relevant feats. Good to know that elf can get two. Exploiter might be interesting to play. Thanks!